# I want to run a VBA code when opening a Power point presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to figure out how i can shuffle the slides in one of my power point presentations when the presentation is opened.

I have the code, but trying to find out how to make it work as power point do not have event handlers. I have tried different solutions but cant get it to work.

I have tried with auto_open add-ins and also different codes but with no luck, thankful for any assistance

The code i want to run when the presentation is opened up by a user:

Sub shuffleRange()

```
Dim Iupper As Integer
Dim ilower As Integer
Dim ifrom As Integer
Dim Ito As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Iupper = 21
ilower = 2

If Iupper > ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Or ilower < 1 Then GoTo Err

For i = 1 To 2 * Iupper
Randomize
ifrom = Int((Iupper - ilower + 1) * Rnd + ilower)
Ito = Int((Iupper - ilower + 1) * Rnd + ilower)
ActivePresentation.Slides(ifrom).MoveTo (Ito)

Next i

Exit Sub
```

Err:
    MsgBox " Shuffle failed", vbCritical

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Untested and swiped from another site but below is a snippet to randomize slides. As far as running at startup though, I don't have a code answer but what if you made a title slide with a begin game/study flashcards/(whatever yours is for) button that runs the macro and turn off advance slide on click?

Sub sort_rand()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim myvalue As Integer
Dim islides As Integer
islides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    myvalue = Int((i * Rnd) + 1)
    ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlideSorter
    ActivePresentation.Slides(myvalue).Select
    ActiveWindow.Selection.Cut
    ActivePresentation.Slides(islides - 1).Select
    ActiveWindow.View.Paste
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: This is like a quiz, and i will use a button to start the quiz (next slide). But the quiz should show the slides randomly, and my code is working perfectly but somehow needs to randomize the slides without the user have to do anything so to say, so i was thinking on doing this at startup so every time you start the presentation, the slides are already randomized.

Comment: I made a button that runs different codes at startup so it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An Auto_Open subroutine will run when an add-in containing it loads but not when a presentation containing it opens.

If you can install an add-in on the user's system, the add-in could set an event trap for the Presentation Open event, examine the newly opened presentation for some feature (name, existence of known shapes on slide/master, tags) that identifies it as "your" presentation and if so, run your existing code.

A google search for "powerpoint events" (sans the quote marks) will point you at more about event handler code in vba